# ls -A (--almost-all) в Windows

Tags: linux, windows

есть ли команда в Windows аналогичная

```
ls -A (--almost-all)?
```

То есть показывающая все файлы, включая скрытые, но игнорирующая текущий и родительский каталоги?
Если такой нет, то возможно ли скрыть текущий и родительский каталоги?

Comment: Можно поставить программу ls на виндовс(cygwin, git-bash) или поискать аналог в powershell

Comment: Проблему решил, команда: dir /a/b

Comment: Можно отвечать на свои вопросы на этом сайте ;)